# Where can I find CVK (Card Verification Key) on EMV card?

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, emv, pcsc

I need to calculate the CVV code after reading an EMV card like Visa, Maestro and Mastercard with a smart card reader.
All websites that allow you to calculate CVV require CVKa and CVKb, but I can't find them on smart card. I also need the 3DES keys.
Does the data need to be read via PIN authentication or is it contained in the certificate?
I searched online for complete file system information but nobody talks about CVK and 3DES keys.
Anyone know how to extract them?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get any 3DES key from the card. Only the issuer of that card will hold it. And you don't need those unless you are a fraudster. If you are trying to implement something based on cards from ground up, then your perception is completely wrong, you need to read more.